# SQL XML creation using query

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am trying to generate XML file code using SQL from Database which has two columns with Duplicate Value
and one column with different values. I used code similar to this

> > DECLARE @SelectXML bit = 1  SELECT @XMLResult = convert(varchar(max),( SELECT distinct  max(Num1) 'Num1'
> >                           , max(Num2) 'Num2'
> >                       ,(case when Side='1' then 'L'
> >                       else 'R' end) 'Num3/Side'
> >                       ,(case when Side='1' then 'L'
> >                       else 'R' end ) 'Num3/Side' From(select  Num1,Num2,Num3 Table1) A group by Side
>
> FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE, ROOT('rootnode')   ))
>
> IF @SelectXML = 1 BEGIN   SELECT convert(xml,@XMLResult) END   Print
>   @XMLResult

which gives result like this

> 

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<rootnode>

<Num1>200</Num1>

<Num2>260.8000</Num2>


-<Num3>

<Side>LL</Side>

</Num3>

<Num1>200</Num1>

<Num2>260.8000</Num2>


-<Num3>

<Side>RR</Side>

</Num3>

</rootnode>
```

I want last Num3 only one column and with Two rows like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<rootnode>

<Num1>200</Num1>

<Num2>260.8000</Num2>


-<Num3>

<Side>L</Side>

<Side>R</Side>

</Num3>

</rootnode>
```

is it possible to add two rows in one column in XML with SQL query

Comment: You need to provide a minimal, reproducible example while asking a question. Please refer to the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following: 
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table() plus INSERT statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code implementation of it. 
(3) Desired output based on the sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have another `for xml subquery` for your `Num3`.

```
DECLARE @XMLResult varchar(max)
DECLARE @SelectXML bit = 1 
SELECT @XMLResult = convert(varchar(max)
    ,( SELECT max(Num1) 'Num1' 
    , max(Num2) 'Num2' 
    , (select 
         max(case when t.Side='1' then 'L' else 'R' end) 'Side'
         From Table1 t
         Where t.Num1 = max(A.Num1) or t.Num2 = max(A.Num2)
         Group by t.Num1, t.Num2
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) 'Num3'
    From Table1 A 

FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE, ROOT('rootnode') ))

IF @SelectXML = 1 BEGIN SELECT convert(xml,@XMLResult) END Print @XMLResult
```